# How to select an option from the GoogleForm non select dropdown using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to select a certain option by automating using python and selenium. I am able to select the text fields by name but I am unsure how to select the dropdowns in the form.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScbs4_3hPNYgjUO-hIa-H1OfJiDZ-FIY1WSk31jGyW5UtQ-Ow/viewform

I have tried using send_keys with getting the element by class but it doesn't seem to work.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption").send_keys("my choice")
```

How can I select an option of my choice from the dropdown in the above form ?

Comment: Hi Zain. Please update your question to include the code you've currently written.

Comment: @PeterSutton I have updated the question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are multiple elements that are returned for this class.

```
.find_element_by_class_name
```

Above returns the first one it finds which happens to not work. The other strategy is to "try-except-click" all of them. See below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScbs4_3hPNYgjUO-hIa-H1OfJiDZ-FIY1WSk31jGyW5UtQ-Ow/viewform")

time.sleep(2)

dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='option']")
dropdown.click()
time.sleep(1)

option_one = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div//span[contains(., 'Option 1')]")
for i in option_one:
    try:
        i.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the option with text as **Option 2** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScbs4_3hPNYgjUO-hIa-H1OfJiDZ-FIY1WSk31jGyW5UtQ-Ow/viewform')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.exportSelectPopup.quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup div.quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption.freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled.exportOption[data-value='Option 2']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScbs4_3hPNYgjUO-hIa-H1OfJiDZ-FIY1WSk31jGyW5UtQ-Ow/viewform')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOptionList']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='exportSelectPopup quantumWizMenuPaperselectPopup']//div[@class='quantumWizMenuPaperselectOption freebirdThemedSelectOptionDarkerDisabled exportOption' and @data-value='Option 2']//span[text()='Option 2']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```